# Integrated Inbox funcitionality in a spring web application

Tags: java, spring, notifications

I have a web application developed using spring, spring security and hibernate. It is used by different users, each belong to a user group. I want to have an inbox functionality. Certain events (e.g. creation of a new object, assigning the object to a user etc.) should generate notification messages. A notification can be addressed to a certain user or a user group. The message consists of a title and the content contains a link to the created object.

In addition administrators should be able to create a message and send it to certian users or groups

The question is is there a framework to provide such a functionality, or it would be a proprietary implementation?

Comment: you can use web socket stomp implementation for real time notifications

Comment: I want the messages to be saved (like for example your inbox in stackoverflow) Whenever the user logs in he can view his inbox. What I understood that STOMP or Websockets are for real-time messages e.g. chat application.